pytorch is_leaf problem
I have a problem about is_leaf of the rotation_matrix i defined below in picture 1.Picture 2 shows how do i get rotation[i] by using getattr to get it from model_params. Picture 3 shows how do i use rotation[i] and print its is_leaf information during the training, because one of my loss calculation needs to use R(rotation[i]), but picture 4 shows the incorrect output of picture 3 as we need self.rotation[i].is_leaf = true. I have try to handle this problem for a weeks but failed, could somebody give me a hint, thanks!




